# How can i create moving element using mouse position, like at http://fieroanimals.com/?

Tags: jquery, image, html, position, mouse

I want to create div element with an image inside, and change it position with coordinates from mouse position. There is a few jquery-pluings for creating 3d effect, but i need only move on X and Y coordinates. Also, do that in limit of div element.

I got next code:

```
$('div.images').mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        $('div.images').css({'top': x,'left': y}); 
    });
```

In CSS div.images have *absolute position*. When i move my mouse is not changing position, but when I delete position in CSS it's apply changes to the style of element, but no change position.

Giv me some advise what I need to do.

At http://fieroanimals.com/ that realised on Flash, but I want do that on JQuery.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('div.moveAble-container').mousemove(function(e){
            var y = e.pageY;
            var x = e.pageX;                    
            $('div.moveAble').css({'top': y}); 
            $('div.moveAble').css({'left': x});

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('div.images').mousemove(...)` implies that it will only detect mouse movements that are over top of `div.images`.

`$('html')` will detect mouse movement over the whole page.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/)

Depending on your needs, you may want apply the X-coordinate to your CSS `left` property and Y-coordinate to CSS `top`. (You have it the other way around in your question).

Comment: Yes. I got that. It's my mistake. On more: How i need to change coordinates for image, so i can move like at http://fieroanimals.com/, for vertical images, for example.

Comment: x and y are inverted. It should be like that:
 `$('div.images').css({'top': y,'left': x}); `